# Getting blank return when using GoQuery to get video src

Tags: go, goquery

I'm trying to get the .mp4 video source of a vine, using GoQuery. However when I run it, I get nothing, no error, or return. Just a blank line.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"

  "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func getMP4URL() {
  doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("https://vine.co/v/MlWtKgwh7WY")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  doc.Find(".vine-video-container").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    mp4, _ := s.Find("video").Attr("src")
    fmt.Printf("MP4: %s", mp4)
  })
}

func main() {
  getMP4URL()
}
```

Is this a problem with my code, or with vine itself?

Comment: Use your browser inspection tool to compare the DOM state with the raw HTML source. You will probably see that the video container is present in the DOM but not in the HTML source. Probably due to browser detection code or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

seems that vine adds that id with javascript

if I add

```
html, err := doc.Html()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println(html)
```

before `doc.Find` there is no `.vine-video-container` in the html output

Answer (score 0):

try this code :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func getMP4URL() {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("https://vine.co/v/MlWtKgwh7WY")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc.Find("meta").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        op, _ := s.Attr("itemprop")
        if op == "contentURL" {
            fmt.Println(s.Attr("content"))
        }
    })
}

func main() {
    getMP4URL()
}
```

Comment: cause the mp4 url defined in the "meta" tag not the "vine-video-container"

Answer (score 0):

Vine embed the metadata of the video in JSON format in the `<script type="application/ld+json">`. So you need to extract the JSON blob from the tag and decode the JSON to get the src of the video.

The following is complete working code to get the src URL of Vine video:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

type SharedContent struct {
    ContentUrl string `json:"contentUrl"`
}

type VineVideoMetadata struct {
    SC SharedContent `json:"sharedContent"`
}

func DecodeVineJsonBlob(blob string) VineVideoMetadata {
    meta := VineVideoMetadata{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(blob), &meta)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return meta
}

func GetVineVideoJsonBlob(url string) string {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return doc.Find("script[type=\"application/ld+json\"]").Text()
}

func GetVineVideoSrc(url string) string {
    jsonBlob := GetVineVideoJsonBlob(url)
    meta := DecodeVineJsonBlob(jsonBlob)
    return meta.SC.ContentUrl
}

func main() {
    println(GetVineVideoSrc("https://vine.co/v/MlWtKgwh7WY"))
}
```

output:

```
https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/67FAC9DFA21115619347885645824_22a564aec15.5.0.17428816123715427422.mp4?versionId=4zcm5ySoFhqUQBXU7Ehm3YOuOSjFbkg3
```